# Appcelerator with syntax javascript lambda

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm download an old project that I have build. So now I have a compilation error like this:

[image: compilation error on <code>=></code>]

I think that appcelerator studio, unknow the syntax LAMBDA of Javascript.

For case, is there a plugin that I should install?

Comment: I think it is not yet available in Titanium JS and currently it is only available in Firefox and Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install any third-party plugins in Appcelerator studio to make this work.

It mostly supports ES5. I believe Lambda expressions are part ES6.

This has more info:
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/ECMA-262-5_Compliance

Comment: but it is possible to install this external module or not?

Comment: @bircastri what you mean by external module?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks to run before (and after) compilation. So what you can do is a hook before compilation that uses babel to transpile your es6 code to es5.

I wrote an example that does just that so Titanium can be used with TypeScript (if you ask me I rather use TypeScript than ES6) - https://github.com/developer82/Ti.TypeScript

You can either use that or use this as an example for setting up similar solution with babel.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have read and execute your guide at that link. I have also import in my workspace, the project ExampleProject, but I can't able to run the application.